# Help! I can't rock out, with my clock out!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I need your help! Look at this:

> *One, two, one o'clock, three o'clock rock*
>   *Eight, six, three o'clock, two o'clock rock*
>   *Nine, seven, one o'clock, seven o'clock rock*
>   *We're gonna rock around the clock tonight*

There's no way I can possibly rock to my maximum potential with a clock that's so obviously broken... **What is causing the hours on my clock to be so messed up?**

---

**Hint 1**:

> There are 24 hours in a day...

**Hint 2**:

> ...and my clock is only a twelve hour clock.

**Hint 3**:

> As much as I like music, the issue here is with my clock.

**Bonus**: Here's what my clock deserves right now...

> *One, two, two o'clock, nine o'clock rock*
>   *Eight, nine, twelve o'clock, one o'clock rock*
>   *Eight, nine, three o'clock, two o'clock rock*
>   *We're gonna rock around the clock tonight*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Kudos to Alconja for creating a puzzle that's so easy and yet has lasted so long unsolved! I dare anyone to disagree that this is easy - *especially* given the hints - after reading the solution below.

---

The hours of the day are usually referred to by a number between $1$ and $12$, even though in fact there are 24 hours in a day. This gives a small ambiguity: "three o'clock" can mean either $3$ or $15$ on a 24-hour clock. (In maths speak, we're considering the 24 hours in their residue classes modulo 12.) Converting these numbers to letters (A=1, B=2, etc.), we can get any letter from A to X from an hour of the day. For instance, "three o'clock" means either C or O.

*One, two, one o'clock, three o'clock rock

Eight, six, three o'clock, two o'clock rock

Nine, seven, one o'clock, seven o'clock rock

We're gonna rock around the clock tonight*

All the "rocking" stuff is just flavour text. Extract the numbers and convert them to letters to get the following, where the $n$th column contains the 2 possibilities for the $n$th number in the song:

```
A B A C H F C B I G A G
M N M O T R O N U S M S
```

So the answer is

> ANACHRONISMS.

For the bonus question, we have:

```
A B B I H I L A H I C B
M N N U T U X M T U O N
```

and so the clock deserves

> ANNIHILATION.

Comment: I've converted them to letters numerous times, changed the values to 24 hour clocks and started calculating with them and such, but never thought of doing both :/ well found!

Comment: "**anachronism** [*uh*-**nak**-r*uh*-niz-*uh* m] *noun* 1. something or someone that is not in its correct historical or chronological time." ...ahh, that explains it! Well done, rand. :)