# It's time to play...Add-A-Gram!

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

Anyone who loves Scrabble or this site is probably familiar with anagrams. But what about Add-A-Grams? An Add-A-Gram takes a word, adds a letter, and then shuffles the letters to make a new word (I guess you can call this an Add-A-Gram's Add-A-Grammar). In this game, I will define an Add-A-Gram chain, and a solution *should contain the complete list of words in the chain*.

For example, if I provided this definition: **depend** *inside* **a race** *inside* **a counselor**

The answer would be: rely -> relay -> lawyer

OK here is the definition for this Add-A-Gram chain:

**a pentomino** *inside* **an element** *inside* **formerly** *inside* **a valley** *inside* **a compound** *inside* **an appendage** *inside* **choose** *inside* **a doctor** *inside* **most ephemeral** *inside* **injuries** *inside* **one without choices** *inside* **an inflammation** *inside* **chamber works**

Happy Add-A-Gramming!

Comment: "An Add-A-Gram takes a word, adds a letter, and then shuffles the letters to make a new word." I guess you can call that the *Add-A-Grammar*.

Comment: I love the teamwork in this site! :D

Comment: Well the final word has to be at least 12 letters...

Comment: I didn't see the edit from Silenus implemented, so I copied it in myself. I hope it was okay to do that!

Comment: @wildBillMunson It's your post :)

Comment: @dcfyj excellent point!

Comment: I've solved up to the appendage. Please tell me the words are not _all_ this obscure.

Comment: No they are not. :)

Comment: I've solved up to the appendage too, but I probably made a few mistakes

Comment: I'm loving these new and imaginative puzzles you're churning out. Keep 'em coming! :-D

Comment: Thanks! I am certainly having a lot of fun, and learning a lot as well! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

pentomino

> N

element

> N + e = Ne (Neon)

formerly

> Ne + e = nee

a valley

> nee + d = dene

a compound

> dene + i = diene

an appendage

> diene + t = endite

choose

> endite + s = destine

a doctor

> destine + r = resident

most ephemeral

> resident + t = trendiest

injuries

> trendiest + m = detriments

one without choices

> detriments + i = determinist

inflammation

> determinist + o = endometritis

chamber works

> endometritis + v = divertimentos

Comment: Wow I'm so impressed! You nailed it!!!! :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson So instead of such obscure words at the beginning, why not something like **N** $\rightarrow$ **EN** $\rightarrow$ **DEN** $\rightarrow$ **SEND** $\rightarrow$ **DENSE** $\rightarrow$ **TENSED** $\rightarrow$ **DESTINE**?  I generally find too many obscure words in a puzzle to be a strike against.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I guess I was trying to make it a bit harder. As it was, with the obscure words, it was solved in under an hour. Next time, I'll try to avoid using too many of these. ;)

Comment: @wildBillMunson I totally understand, but I would suggest that you try to make it harder by making the *clues* a little more obscure, rather than the solution.  Also, a puzzle that's solved quickly (especially on Puzzling.SE) is not necessarily a bad puzzle (in fact, I would say if it takes too long to solve, it is, with very few exceptions, *not* a great puzzle).

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain OK I like that plan! For the next one, I'll find an Add-A-Gram chain of words we actually use, and use clues like from a crossword puzzle. Thanks for the advice! :)

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Some of the best puzzles on the site have taken a very long time to solve, like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15187/5373) and maybe [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15852/5373). I might agree that most puzzles which take a long time to solve aren't great (well, most puzzles aren't great, full stop), but I'd also posit that many if not most great puzzles take a long time to solve.

Comment: @randal'thor You'll note that both of those questions required numerous hints before they were solved. I would argue that while the *premise* of both was excellent, the *presentation* lacked sufficient hints to lead the solver in the right direction. Looking at them in retrospect, they look like great puzzles, but in truth they required too great a leap of intuition to be solved without further prodding from the OP.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I recognised paco's ("22/48 intrinsically") as a great puzzle from the outset - it was clear that the right answer would be self-confirming, and it just needed someone to have the right idea. The fact that it took the brilliance of McMag to finally solve it doesn't lessen its greatness, IMO. As for Alco's ("rock out"), I still don't understand how that wasn't solved within hours - when you look at it the right way, it's blindingly obvious, even without the hints.