# Add-A-Gram marathon!

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

This is based on the [Add-A-Gram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/its-time-to-play-add-a-gram) puzzles by [wildBillMunson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/6094/wildbillmunson). You need to find a chain of words, such that each next word is an anagram of the previous word plus an additional letter.

a **Tasty bone** in **British gratitude** in a **Roasted fashion** in **great** in **secret** in a **Stone** in **peculiar** in a **rank** in **far** in **slanders** in **grave robbing**

Good luck!

Comment: Haha it's fun to see what other puzzlers do with this! :) +1

Comment: this was a good one! I also like how you shortened 'inside' to 'in'. :)

Comment: @wildBillMunson thanks for the nice puzzle idea. Might have to consider using slang words and expression or people names etc. Using tools online makes it too easy to solve with normal words I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes that's true. Online tools don't usually include proper nouns. Excellent idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This time it's ...

> a Tasty bone — *T*
>  British gratitude — *ta*
>  a Roasted fashion — *tan*    [originally had *tea*]
>  great — *neat*
>  secret — *agent* ?!
>  a Stone — *garnet*
>  peculiar — *strange*
>  a rank — *sergeant*
>  far — *estranged*
>  slanders — *denigrates*
>  grave robbing — *desecrating*

Comment: OMG you beat me by like 5 seconds! Argh!!!!

Comment: 5... 93.... who's counting ;)

Comment: Nice job! :) +1

Comment: Wow, can't believe you made it work with 1 wrong word XD. Think you can find the desired "roasted fashion?"

Comment: Fixed now... :)

Comment: Good job! You got it.