# Are we bored of add-a-grams yet? Because I've got another short one

Tags: word, anagram

This is based on the [Add-A-Gram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/its-time-to-play-add-a-gram) puzzles by [wildBillMunson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/6094/wildbillmunson). You need to find a chain of words, such that each next word is an anagram of the previous word plus an additional letter.

For example, **suitable** inside **a fool** inside **many covers** might be solved with apt -> prat -> tarps

For this particular puzzle, your clues are:

**A snake** inside **deadly poison** inside **Jamaican music** inside **fencing equipment** inside **assigns scores** inside **a belligerent name** inside **a seasonal demon**

Hope you have fun with it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's see...

> A Snake - S (not sure about this one)
>  Deadly Poison - As (Which is short for Arsenic)
>  Jamaican Music - Ska
>  Fencing Equipment - Mask
>  Assigns Scores - Marks
>  Belligerent Name - Markus (Roman name)
>  Seasonal Demon - Krampus (known for the Christmas season and movie)

Comment: Gah, was so close to posting this, The first one is because of the shape of the letter :)

Comment: @DrunkWolf Yes, I thought so too. Wasn't too sure about this though. :)

Answer (score 3):

Mike beat me to it :(

A snake

> S (shape of snake)

A deadly poison

> As (arsenic)

Jamaican music

> Ska (originated in Jamaica)

Fencing equipment

> Mask (used in fencing)

Assigns scores

> Marks

Belligerent name

> Markus (Marcus can refer to Mars, god of war, Markus is an alternative spelling)

Seasonal demon

> Krampus

Comment: Slightly slower than Mike, but it seems like you're the only one who spotted that Markus is derived from Mars. Nice one. I should have tried to make this one harder...

Answer (score 3):

A snake

> **S**

inside deadly poison

> **AS(Arsenic poisoning)**

inside Jamaican music

> **SKA**

inside fencing equipment

> **MASK**

inside assigns scores

> **MARKS**

inside a belligerent name

> **Markus**

inside a seasonal demon

> [**Krampus**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krampus)

Comment: Oh... Too late!