# A Riddle of Successive Subtractive Sentences

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

> All in all: out of bed! Time the morning to greet!
>   Minus one and the statesman is losing his seat.
>   Minus two: it's a hue or a kind of a smirch.
>   Minus three, in a way, nothing short of a perch.
>   Minus four, time to flee! Run away in defeat!
>   Minus five, a big rat a king's daughter might meet.

The answer is a single English word.

Added the trivia tag for the last line.

Comment: Do we rearrange letters between words?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore No rearrangement needed.

Comment: Think I have a few, is it only the first letter that is removed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure any letter can be removed

Comment: This seems like a deluxe version of the [Add-A-Gram](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47851).

Comment: Does each line refer to a single word?

Comment: @wildBillMunson Yes. Each line refers to a single word.

Comment: And, just to be clear, minus N+1 is always obtained by removing one letter from minus N (rather than each being an independent subtraction from the original word)?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Good question. I missed Add-A-Gram so maybe this is misleading. Each line is an independent operation on the original word.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain *... or does it?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> ROUST.

*All in all: out of bed! Time the morning to greet!*

> Definition of ROUST.

*Minus one and the statesman is losing his seat.*

> The statesman is OUSTed.

*Minus two: it's a hue or a kind of a smirch.*

> RUST can be a colour or a smirch.

*Minus three, in a way, nothing short of a perch.*

> ROST - one letter short of a roost.

*Minus four, time to flee! Run away in defeat!*

> The fleeing army is in a ROUT.

*Minus five, a big rat a king's daughter might meet.*

> [ROUS](http://princessbride.wikia.com/wiki/R.O.U.S.)
>
>  [image: princess bride]

---

**Feedback section**

Excellent riddle. Once I got the right answer, pretty much everything fell into place perfectly; nothing else could have fit the clues.
I got the last line first (being a fantasy buff probably helped - I'd had that particular work in mind for a long time even when I was thinking the answer would be PEA), and then the second-to-last line followed quite easily as the two words are similar.
At that point I was confused, having assumed each line described a word with one fewer letter than the previous line. But the singular version fit better than the plural for the second-to-last line, and I had a niggling feeling that maybe the numbers referred to positions rather than numbers of letters. And when I tried this idea, it worked perfectly right away.

Comment: Well done! My sincere congratulations!

Comment: @Hugh Aha, that fits! Answer completed and feedback section added.

Comment: Oh, very nice. I fell into (I think) the same trap as just about everyone else -- I thought it was a matter of removing more and more letters for each line. I'm not sure whether that was a deliberate red herring (if so, I think maybe a little unfair?) or accident.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I meant to leave the meaning of the minuses up in the air but I didn't mean to positively imply something other than the actual solution. I'm not sure why pretty much everyone took the same wrong path at first. Maybe the similarities to Add-A-Gram (which I hadn't seen) or maybe the word "successive" in the title was a poor choice.