# Return of the Add-A-Gram!

Tags: word, knowledge, anagram

This game is based on the [Add-A-Gram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/its-time-to-play-add-a-gram) puzzles by [wildBillMunson](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/6094/wildbillmunson). I think it's the 11th in the series, but who's really keeping count?

The goal: You need to find a chain of words, such that each next word is an anagram of the previous word plus an additional letter. You are given the meanings of the words, in order.

Example: ***a gas*** in **a disjunction** in **a bird** in **a center** in **an influence**.
The solution is O < OR < ROC < CORE < FORCE. You can format your answer however you want.

Here is the chain for you to solve:

> **a pole** in **a tenth** in **a forest dweller** in **a branch** in **a container** in **a separate leaf** in **igneous rocks** in **a sax player** in **a pen vendor** in **versions** in **a Middle Eastern artist** in **reprisals** in **sound repetitions** in **reestablishment**.

Each one is a single word. That's 14 different words in total. Can you identify them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> <strike>E</strike> N (North)
> <strike>TE</strike> <strike>EN</strike> NE (10th element, @somebody)
> ENT
> TINE
> STEIN
> INSERT
> NORITES
> TENORIST
> STATIONER
> ITERATIONS
> ORIENTALIST
> RETALIATIONS
> ALLITERATIONS
> REINSTALLATION

Comment: I found this: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Mindrones/Wiki/Subdivision_modelling/The_pole/E_and_N_poles
and convinced myself that from "do" to "te" on a musical scale is a "tenth" interval. not sure if that's true, though.

Comment: ^ is not correct.

Comment: @kayzeroshort can you explain the first two? i don't quite understand.

Comment: do to te is a ninth, I'm afraid.

Comment: @kayzeroshort 10 is Ne (Neon, tenth element)

Comment: @somebody good call.