# Rock around the old oak tree

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, humor

> I'm the reason why Ireland doesn't sink,
>   And what sometimes keeps people from the drink,
>   I'm not Fahrenheit, my choice tells you that,
>   Rotten rotten me, almost proved Fermat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I gotta be...

> > ... **C O  R  K**
>
> The title, “**Rock** around the old **oak tree**,”
>   refers to this riddle’s answer
>   and first line in at least three ways:
>
> > “[Rock Around the Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_Around_the_Clock)”
> >  and
> >  “[Tie a Yellow Ribbon Round the Ole Oak Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_a_Yellow_Ribbon_Round_the_Ole_Oak_Tree)”
> >  are well-known rock songs
> >  and [*Cork **Rock***](https://books.google.com/books/about/Cork_Rock.html?id=SkWrngEACAAJ)
> >  is a book about rock music in
> >  [County Cork, Ireland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Cork).
> >  
> >
> >  Better— thanks to
> >  [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit)**:**
> >    “**rock**” turned “around”
> >  spells “cork.”
> >  
> >
> >  Corks are traditionally made from the bark of
> >  [cork **oak trees**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_suber).
>
> I’m the reason why Ireland doesn’t sink,
>
> > **Cork**
> >  ([a city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_(city)),
> >  and [its county](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Cork))
> >  is in Ireland
> >  and **cork** (the bark of
> >  [cork oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_suber))
> >  floats.
>
> And what sometimes keeps people from the drink,
>
> > Can’t guzzle without un**cork**ing the bottle.
>
> I’m not Fahrenheit, my choice tells you that,
>
> > I’m **C  o r  K** (Celsius or Kelvin),
> >  [Jim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_McCoy#.22I.27m_a_doctor.2C_not_a.28n.29....22),
> >  not an F (Fahrenheit).
>
> **Rotten rotten** me, **almost** proved **Fermat**.
>
> > More thanks to
> >     [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit),
> >     for solving the
> >     [pyramidion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramidion)
> >     of this riddle**:**
>
> > Two applications to “C O R K” of
> >  [alphabetic **rot**ation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)
> >  by **ten** steps
> >  produces “W I L E,”
> >  which **almost** spells “Wiles,”
> >  the last name of
> >  [the mathematician who proved **Fermat**’s Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).
> >
> > ```
> >          Original             After                 After another
> >         letter and           rot-ten                   rot-ten
> >        alphabetical       (rotation by              (rotation by
> >          position           10 steps)                 10 steps)
> >
> >           C    3  - - - -  13   M   13  - - - - - -  23   W   23
> >           O   15  - - - -  25   Y   25  - - - - - -  35   I    9 (=35-26)
> >           R   18  - - - -  28   B    2 (=28-26) - -  12   L   12
> >           K   11  - - - -  21   U   21  - - - - - -  31   E    5 (=31-26)
> >           +                                               +
> >           Y   25  - - - -  35   I    9 (=35-26) - -  19   S   19
> > ```
> >
> > Frosting on the cake,
> >  from a comment by this puzzle’s author**:**
> >  
> >
> >          
> >  “Corky Rotscore proved Fermat’s Last Theorem”

Comment: First revision will note how the answer to line 1 jibes with the riddle's title

Comment: What first revision?

Comment: First revision to this answer, now entered, still without a solid lead on the last line

Comment: Ah, I see with the "not Fahrenheit" part. That makes me now think you've got the right answer.

Comment: Hurray, @Ankoganit, you should post that (and the anagram) and at least get some official credit! Then this answer could also reference yours. I think the last line is the high card of this riddle (and you can bet I've spent the last hour reading everything about Wiles and partial-provers).

Comment: Also, regarding the *rotten* clue: the past tense of *cork* somewhat crudely describes the *n>2* case.

Comment: I wonder who Jim is. (On Kelvin I like the story where when the Tripos results were posted he sent his man to see who was second place in the list, and was told 'Your are Sir!', the reason being Thomson at that time didn't revise a result he had discovered thinking it wouldn't be set, but the other guy did. Another one is when knighted he returned to local QUB and took over from a lecturer named Day. Apparently he was bad and when he left the students wrote on the board something like Thankfully Night has turned into Day.)

Comment: Links have been added, @Tom, including one for the gratuitous "Jim" hail. Thank you for a rare riddle that I could even partially solve. The 1/4-O-Donnell in me got to join the fun.

Comment: Oky doke, @Ankoganit, **rotten** has been gratefully incorporated and duly credited

Comment: [Speaking of rocking around the clock ...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15852/5373) (cc @Tom)

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna guess:

> Degree.

I'm the reason why Ireland doesn't sink,

> I'm guessing the temperature (weather) not causing the sea to rise high enough to sink Ireland.

And what sometimes keeps people from the drink,

> I checked the statistics and people with higher education drink more. So maybe it's a reference to how people without a degree (and lower pay) are financially kept from being able to purchase as much alchohol.

I'm not Fahrenheit, my choice tells you that,

> I can only guess that's a reference to Europe using Celsius.

Rotten rotten me, almost proved Fermat.

> Perhaps a reference to Fermat's Last Theorem and the mathematical degrees, when if greater than 2 with all positive integers becomes an unsolvable equasion. ([image: see image])

Comment: Good answer.  The second line may have been clearer if asked  'And I'm the last light obstacle to drink'